# SIGSEGV error in C++ with character pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, c-strings

Why I am getting a SIGSEGV error in this program:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char *name1, *name2;
    cout<<"Enter your name: ";
    cin>>name1;
    strcpy(name2, name1);
    cout<<"Your name is: "<<name2<<endl<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please explain to me why I am getting a SIGSEGC error. This program shows error with character pointer (char *name1, *name2) but, works fine with character arrays (char name1[20], name2[20]) and also with dynamic memory allocator **new** (char *name1=new char[20] and char *name2=new char[20])

Answer (score 1):

Your program segfaults because you have not allocated memory for `name1` and `name2`. Your program is writing the input from cin into a undefined memory location which causes it to crash with SIGSEGV.

Comment: I got it... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

These declared variables

```
char *name1, *name2;
```

are not initialized and have indeterminate values.

As a result these statements

```
cin>>name1;
strcpy(name2, name1);
```

invoke undefined behavior.

Use objects of the standard class std::string. For example

```
#include <string>

//...

std::string name1, name2;
//...
cin>>name1;
name2 = name1;
//...
```

Otherwise you need to declare character arrays for example like

```
const size_t N = 100;
char name1[N], name2[N];
```

and then to write

```
cin.getline( name1, sizeof( name1 ) );
strcpy(name2, name1);
```

Comment: Okay... now I got it... thank you very much.